# storage device does not appear on my desktop mac os x

Tags: macos

When I plugin in my USB device into my MacBook, it doesn't show up on the desktop.

I googled about it but I couldn't find anything.

How can I enable this option ?

Comment: It would help to have more information on the storage device (format, size, on which devices did it work before or is it completely new?) and the macbook (which usb devices worked before?) etc.

Comment: Does it show up in Disk Utility? Have you [enabled showing external disks on the desktop in Finder preferences](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TjT3F.png)?